# What is radio frequency microwave energy used for?

Tags: microwaves

Yesterday, the X-37B landed in Florida after 3,774 days in space orbiting earth since 2010.  It was said to be transmitting radio frequency microwave energy towards earth for experimentation.  What is this particular EMF used for?  I just posted a question about the EM Drive yesterday at precisely the time this ship landed and I don't really use this site much at all, so I hope there is a really good reason for this coincidence.

https://nypost.com/2022/11/13/secretive-space-ship-lands-in-florida/

Comment: "X-37B’s primary missions are mainly secretive" - what makes you think we would know or could reveal it if we did? Anything we might say on the topic would be purely speculative (= opinion-based and off-topic), or contain classified military information which would result in enforced trips to unfavourable government-locations. There is: “successfully harnessed solar rays outside of Earth’s atmosphere and aimed to transmit power to the ground in the form of radio frequency microwave energy,” - do you mean to ask about that? Please edit the question to be more specific and answerable.

Comment: *I hope there is a really good reason for this coincidence.* This coincidence has nothing to do with physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microwaves have [many applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave#Microwave_uses). I believe the experiment you refer to is one that tested beaming solar energy collected in space to ground using microwaves.

Comment: @SolomonSlow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power this is really not for military application although making a precise steerable phased array to form a tight beam is the basis of most modern radar.